# Swagger not accepting values in UI

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I'm observing strange behavior only for PATCH API swagger documentation. Path variables are marked as "ref" parameters and are not accepting values for submission.

[image]

Note that, this is not happening for GET, POST or PUT API documentations. You can see the difference below.

[image]

Here are the swagger API config:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "update Jurisdictions", response = JurisdictionDto.class, authorizations = {@Authorization(value = "oauth2schema")})
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized", response = AuthenticationError.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Access Denied", response = AuthorizationError.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not found", response = NotFoundError.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error", response = InternalServerError.class)
})
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "jurisdiction", value = "jurisdiction", required = true, dataType = "integer", paramType = "path"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(
                name = "patch",
                value = "patch",
                dataType = "JsonPatchProperty",
                required = true)
})
@PatchMapping(value = "/v1/jurisdictions/{jurisdiction}", consumes = "application/json-patch+json")
public ResponseEntity<JurisdictionDto> updateJurisdiction(@PathVariable("jurisdiction") long id,
                                                          @RequestBody(required = true) JsonPatch patch) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(jurisdictionSvc.getAndUpdate(id, patch));
}
```

Can someone tell me what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use object type `Long` instead of primitive `long` as method argument.

Comment: My GET api has primitive `long` and it is working without issues. This only happens with my PATCH api documentation.